# ObjectMapper to Serialize as a map

Tags: java, jackson

I have a bean that internally uses a map

```
class MyBean { 
    private Map<String,String> map;
    public MyBean(String key, String value) {
       map = Collections.singletonMap(key, value);
    }
}
```

I want to serialize it so it uses the underlaying map as its representation
`{"akey":"avalue"}`

```
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapperWriteValueAsString(new MyBean("akey", "avalue"));
```

but the default serialization returns the map attribute

```
{"map":{"akey":"avalue"}}
```

I managed to create a custom serializer that uses the map attribute. Is this the only way to achieve it?

```
private static class MyBeanSerializer extends StdSerializer<MyBean> {

    public MyBeanSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MyBeanSerializer(Class<MyBean> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyBean value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeObject(value.map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the @JsonUnwrapped annotation:

```
class MyBean {
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private Map<String,String> map;
  public MyBean(String key, String value) {
     map = Collections.singletonMap(key, value);
  }
}
```